Can a contradiction Boolean expression with variables  and  be represented in NAND form?
I have f(a,b) = 0 and want to represent it in NAND form (only using NAND gates) in terms of a and b, but I don't think is possible.

You can do any boolean expression with NAND gates, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic

def NAND(a, b):
    return (a & b) ^ 1

def f(a, b):
    return NAND(
        NAND(a, NAND(a, a)),
        NAND(b, NAND(b, b)),
    )

for a in 0, 1:
    for b in 0, 1:
        print(f(a, b))

Output (Attempt This Online!):
0
0
0
0


@Kelly Bundy
The problem is to write this expression in NAND form:
¬(¬(¬((X∧Y)∨(X↔Y))∨(Y∧Z))∨¬((U⊼¬X)⊽(Y⊼X)))
Where:

↔ is XOR (exclusive OR).
⊼ is NAND (negated AND).
¬ is NOT (negation).
∧ is AND (conjunction).
∨ is OR (disjunction).
⊽ is NOR (negated OR).


@Glooring Sorry, I don't understand. To be clear: I meant why this answer was downvoted.

I upvoted your answer, I don't know.
